# twisted installed on mac os x but not importing

Tags: python, macos, installation, twisted

When I try to use twisted from python it fails to load.  Extras path is not in my sys.path.  Even when I add it to sys.path it fails to load twisted.  Any ideas?

```
sudo find / -name twisted
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/twisted
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84374, Aug 31 2010, 11:00:51) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that all permissions are set properly? If you installed it by hand it might be a problem with the permissions. Check that the permissions are 644 for files and 755 for directories.

Comment: something weird with my python install I think because easy_install points to 2.7 but python is 2.6.6